# How to set a variable in one class and get it in another

Tags: java, variables, get, set, accessor

Once I have set the "set" method in one class to set my accessor, is it possible to return(get) that variable/string in another class without first having to "set" the variable again?

```
public class A {
Edits edits = new Edits("hello") }
```

now I want to access this from class B

```
public class B {
Edits edits = new Edits();
String hello = edits.getHello(); }
```

Problem is that there is and error initializing "new Edits()" because it first has to be set.

Comment: A class or an instance of a class? If it's a class, and you're talking about a static member, then yes, as long as the application is alive (which depends on the environment we're talking about). If it's an instance, yes as long as that instance is alive.

Comment: From another class, the problem is how to retrieve it without initializing the accessor again.

Comment: I didn't make myself clear. Suppose you have a class named `A` with a static setter named `setA(int a)` and a static getter `getA()`. You can do `A.setA(12)` and then from inside another class you can do `A.getA()`. Is this what you're asking?

Comment: are you planning on only creating one instance of a class, like a singleton?

Comment: @ Federico yes exactly

Comment: Ok, after your edit I see what you mean. That `edits` is a different instance of the `Edits` class. So unless the variable (member) you previously set was static, the getter will *not* refer to the variable you previously set with the setter.

Comment: Is there a way around it?

Comment: Also, no, seeing your example that's not *exactly* what I was saying in my previous comment, quite the opposite. You seem to be a bit confused by the difference between a class and an instance. If that's the case I suggest you read up on it.

Comment: "*Is there a way around it?*" depends on what you're trying to achieve. Probably depperm's suggestion is the correct one: the word you're looking for may be `singleton`, but there's not enough info in your question to be positive about this.

Comment: I edited my question.

Comment: If you'll always need **just one** instance of `Edits` a singleton is the answer you're looking for. Otherwise you'll have to be more precise about what you're trying to do. As it stands, I confirm that those two instances of `Edits` share nothing. Either mark whatever the first constructor set as `static` in the class definition or look for the word "singleton" on your favorite search engine.

Comment: Your example creates two instances of "Edits". One holds the value "Hello", the other doesn't.

Comment: @ mick, It holds nothing because the second time it throws and error. because it has to be set.

Comment: @ federico, I believe you are correct. Thank you

Comment: However the problem is that a singleton is not meant to be initiated from another class. I need to initialize from one class and get it from another class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer here is actually quite simple. All you do it declare a static variable and call it with the class from another class.

```
public class Edits {
    public static String edits;
}
```

Set it in another class

```
public class A {
    Edits.edits = "new value";
}
```

Then get it from another class

```
public class B {
    doSomething(Edits.edits);
}
```